# Rear Camera preview with SurfaceTexture is being mirrored i want it in the normal way

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, camera, face-detection

I'm trying to do something with the rear Camera but when i try my code the camera preview is displayed mirrored(left-to-right)...
Maybe i've written something wrong! I'm using the FSDK that is a private library.
Here is the code:

```
public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = 0;
public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_PORTRAIT = 1;
public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 2;
public static final int DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_LANDSCAPE = 3;
private Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo;
public volatile int deviceOrientation = DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
private FSDK.HTracker tracker;
public Matrix transform;
private int[] textures;
private Camera camera;
private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;
private boolean updateSurfaceTexture = false;
private FSDK.FSDK_Features[] trackingFeatures;
private MR.MaskFeatures maskCoords;
private int[] isMaskTexture1Created = new int[]{0};
private int[] isMaskTexture2Created = new int[]{0};
private int width;
private int height;
private ByteBuffer pixelBuffer;
private FSDK.HImage cameraImage = new FSDK.HImage();
private FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE cameraImageMode = new FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE();
private FSDK.HImage snapshotImage = new FSDK.HImage();
private FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE snapshotImageMode = new FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE();
private MainView mainView;
private MainActivity mainActivity;
private volatile boolean isResizeCalled = false;
private volatile boolean isResized = false;
public long IDs[] = new long[MR.MAX_FACES];
public long face_count[] = new long[1];
private long frameCount = 0;
private long startTime = 0;
private AtomicBoolean isTakingSnapshot = new AtomicBoolean(false);
public static final int[][] MASKS = new int[][]{
        {R.raw.lips_pink, R.drawable.lips_pink, R.drawable.lips_pink_normal, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO},
        {R.raw.lips_purple, R.drawable.lips_purple, R.drawable.lips_purple_normal, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO},
        {R.raw.lips_red, R.drawable.lips_red, R.drawable.lips_red_normal, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO},
};
private int mask = 0;
private int maskLoaded = 0;
private volatile boolean isMaskChanged = false;
private boolean inPreview = false;
public void changeMask(int i) {
    mask += i;
    isMaskChanged = true;
}
public MainRenderer(MainView view) {
    tracker = Application.tracker;
    mainView = view;
    mainActivity = (MainActivity) mainView.getContext();
    trackingFeatures = new FSDK.FSDK_Features[MR.MAX_FACES];
    for (int i = 0; i < MR.MAX_FACES; ++i) {
        trackingFeatures[i] = new FSDK.FSDK_Features();
        for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
            trackingFeatures[i].features[j] = new FSDK.TPoint();
        }
    }
    maskCoords = new MR.MaskFeatures();
}
public void close() {
    /*updateSurfaceTexture = false;
    surfaceTexture.release();
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    deleteTex();*/
}
public void startCamera() {
    if (inPreview) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        inPreview = false;
    }
    camera.release();
    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        cameraInfo.facing = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
    } else {
        cameraInfo.facing = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    }
    camera = Camera.open(cameraInfo.facing);

    final Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    int rotation = mainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mainActivity.mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.height, previewSize.width));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            transform.setScale(-1, 1, previewSize.height / 2, 0);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mainActivity.mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.width, previewSize.height));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            transform.setScale(-1, 1, previewSize.width / 2, 0);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mainActivity.mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.height, previewSize.width));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            transform.setScale(-1, 1, previewSize.height / 2, 0);
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            mainActivity.mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.width, previewSize.height));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            transform.setScale(-1, 1, previewSize.width / 2, 0);
            break;
    }

    try {
        camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    camera.startPreview();
    inPreview = true;
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) { 
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
    isResizeCalled = false;
    isResized = false;

    initTex();
    loadMask(mask);

    surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textures[0]);
    surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

    int cameraId = 0;
    boolean frontCameraFound = false;
    cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraInfo.facing = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    camera = Camera.open(0);

    transform = new Matrix();

    final Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    int rotation = mainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mainActivity.mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.height, previewSize.width));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            transform.setScale(-1, 1, previewSize.height / 2, 0);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mainActivity.mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.width, previewSize.height));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            transform.setScale(-1, 1, previewSize.width / 2, 0);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mainActivity.mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.height, previewSize.width));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            transform.setScale(-1, 1, previewSize.height / 2, 0);
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            mainActivity.mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.width, previewSize.height));
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            transform.setScale(-1, 1, previewSize.width / 2, 0);
            break;
    }

    try {
        camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GLES11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
}

private byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 16384;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int len;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
public void loadMask(int maskNumber) {
    GLES11.glDisable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);

    Log.d(TAG, "Loading mask...");

    int[] mask = MASKS[maskNumber];

    if (isMaskTexture1Created[0] > 0) {
        GLES11.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, 1);
    }
    if (isMaskTexture2Created[0] > 0) {
        GLES11.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, 2);
    }

    isMaskTexture1Created[0] = 0;
    isMaskTexture2Created[0] = 0;

    InputStream stream = mainView.getResources().openRawResource(mask[0]);
    int res = MR.LoadMaskCoordsFromStream(stream, maskCoords);
    try {
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (res != FSDK.FSDKE_OK) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading mask coords from stream: " + res);
        GLES11.glEnable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
        return;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapDecodingOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapDecodingOptions.inScaled = false;

    FSDK.HImage img1 = new FSDK.HImage();
    if (mask[1] == -1) {
        FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img1);
    } else {
        stream = mainView.getResources().openRawResource(mask[1]);
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            data = readBytes(stream);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (data != null) {
            res = FSDK.LoadImageFromPngBufferWithAlpha(img1, data, data.length);
            Log.d(TAG, "Load mask image of size " + data.length + " with result " + res);
            int[] w = new int[]{0};
            int[] h = new int[]{0};
            FSDK.GetImageWidth(img1, w);
            FSDK.GetImageHeight(img1, h);
            Log.d(TAG, "Mask image size: " + w[0] + " x " + h[0]);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error loading mask image, using empty image");
            FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img1);
        }
    }

    FSDK.HImage img2 = new FSDK.HImage();
    if (mask[2] == -1) { 
        FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img2);
    } else {
        stream = mainView.getResources().openRawResource(mask[2]);
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            data = readBytes(stream);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (data != null) {
            res = FSDK.LoadImageFromPngBufferWithAlpha(img2, data, data.length);
            Log.d(TAG, "Load mask normal image of size " + data.length + " with result " + res);
            int[] w = new int[]{0};
            int[] h = new int[]{0};
            FSDK.GetImageWidth(img2, w);
            FSDK.GetImageHeight(img2, h);
            Log.d(TAG, "Mask normal image size: " + w[0] + " x " + h[0]);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error loading mask normal image, using empty image");
            FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(img2);
        }
    }

    res = MR.LoadMask(img1, img2, textures[1], textures[2], isMaskTexture1Created, isMaskTexture2Created);
    FSDK.FreeImage(img1);
    FSDK.FreeImage(img2);

    Log.d(TAG, "Mask loaded with result " + res + " texture1Created:" + isMaskTexture1Created[0] + " texture2Created:" + isMaskTexture2Created[0]);
    Log.d(TAG, "Mask textures: " + textures[1] + " " + textures[2]);

    GLES11.glEnable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    GLES11.glClear(GLES11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (!isResized) {
        return;
    }

    synchronized (this) {
        if (updateSurfaceTexture) {
            surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
            updateSurfaceTexture = false;
        }
    }

    if (isMaskChanged) {
        maskLoaded = mask;
        loadMask(mask);
        isMaskChanged = false;
    }

    int rotation;
    if (cameraInfo.facing == 1) {
        rotation = 1;
    } else {
        rotation = -1;
    }

    int res = MR.DrawGLScene(textures[0], 0, trackingFeatures, rotation, MR.SHIFT_TYPE_NO, textures[1], textures[2], maskCoords, 0, 0, width, height);
    if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in the first MR.DrawGLScene call: " + res);
    }
    GLES11.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES11.GL_RGBA, GLES11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);

    face_count[0] = 0;

    if (cameraInfo.facing == 1) {
        processCameraImageFront();
    }
    if (cameraInfo.facing == 0) {
        processCameraImageRear();
    }

    res = MR.DrawGLScene(textures[0], (int) face_count[0], trackingFeatures, rotation, MASKS[maskLoaded][3], textures[1], textures[2], maskCoords, isMaskTexture1Created[0], isMaskTexture2Created[0], width, height);
    if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in the second MR.DrawGLScene call: " + res);
    }

    if (isTakingSnapshot.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
        GLES11.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES11.GL_RGBA, GLES11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);
        snapshotImageMode.mode = FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE.FSDK_IMAGE_COLOR_32BIT;
        res = FSDK.LoadImageFromBuffer(snapshotImage, pixelBuffer.array(), width, height, width * 4, snapshotImageMode);
        if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading snapshot image to FaceSDK: " + res);
        } else {

            FSDK.MirrorImage(snapshotImage, false);

            String galleryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath();
            final String filename = galleryPath + "/MirrorRealityDemo" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
            res = FSDK.SaveImageToFile(snapshotImage, filename);
            Log.d(TAG, "saving snapshot to " + filename);

            FSDK.FreeImage(snapshotImage);

            if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK == res) {
                mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                        File f = new File(filename);
                        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                        mainActivity.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

                        Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    ++frameCount;
    long timeCurrent = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (startTime == 0) startTime = timeCurrent;
    long diff = timeCurrent - startTime;
    if (diff >= 3000) {
        final float fps = frameCount / (diff / 1000.0f);
        frameCount = 0;
        startTime = 0;

        final TextView fpsTextView = mainActivity.fpsTextView();
        mainActivity.fpsTextView().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!mainActivity.isFinishing()) {
                    fpsTextView.setText(fps + " FPS");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void processCameraImageFront() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MR.MAX_FACES; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
            trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = 0;
            trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = 0;
        }
    }

    cameraImageMode.mode = FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE.FSDK_IMAGE_COLOR_32BIT;
    int res = FSDK.LoadImageFromBuffer(cameraImage, pixelBuffer.array(), width, height, width * 4, cameraImageMode);
    if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading camera image to FaceSDK: " + res);
        return;
    }

    int[] widthByReference = new int[1];
    int[] heightByReference = new int[1];
    FSDK.GetImageWidth(cameraImage, widthByReference);
    FSDK.GetImageHeight(cameraImage, heightByReference);
    int width = widthByReference[0];
    int height = heightByReference[0];

    int rotation = 0;
    if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_PORTRAIT) {
        rotation = 2;
    } else if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        rotation = 3;
    } else if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_LANDSCAPE) {
        rotation = 1;
    }

    if (rotation > 0) {
        FSDK.HImage rotated = new FSDK.HImage();
        FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(rotated);
        FSDK.RotateImage90(cameraImage, rotation, rotated);
        FSDK.FeedFrame(tracker, 0, rotated, face_count, IDs);
        FSDK.FreeImage(rotated);
    } else {
        FSDK.FeedFrame(tracker, 0, cameraImage, face_count, IDs);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < (int) face_count[0]; ++i) {
        FSDK.GetTrackerFacialFeatures(tracker, 0, IDs[i], trackingFeatures[i]);
        if (rotation > 0) {
            if (rotation == 1) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                    int x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = height - 1 - x;
                }
            } else if (rotation == 2) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = width - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = height - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                }
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                    int x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = width - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = x;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    FSDK.FreeImage(cameraImage);
}

private void processCameraImageRear() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MR.MAX_FACES; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
            trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = 0;
            trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = 0;
        }
    }

    cameraImageMode.mode = FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE.FSDK_IMAGE_COLOR_32BIT;
    int res = FSDK.LoadImageFromBuffer(cameraImage, pixelBuffer.array(), width, height, width * 4, cameraImageMode);
    if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != res) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading camera image to FaceSDK: " + res);
        return;
    }

    int[] widthByReference = new int[1];
    int[] heightByReference = new int[1];
    FSDK.GetImageWidth(cameraImage, widthByReference);
    FSDK.GetImageHeight(cameraImage, heightByReference);
    int width = widthByReference[0];
    int height = heightByReference[0];
    /*int rotation = 0;
    if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        rotation = 0;
    } else if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_PORTRAIT) {
        rotation = 2;
    } else if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        rotation = 3;
    } else if (deviceOrientation == DEVICE_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_LANDSCAPE) {
        rotation = 1;
    }*/

    int rotation = 1;
    if (rotation > 0) {
        FSDK.HImage rotated = new FSDK.HImage();
        FSDK.CreateEmptyImage(rotated);
        FSDK.FeedFrame(tracker, 0, rotated, face_count, IDs);
        FSDK.FreeImage(rotated);
    } else {
        FSDK.FeedFrame(tracker, 0, cameraImage, face_count, IDs);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < (int) face_count[0]; ++i) {
        FSDK.GetTrackerFacialFeatures(tracker, 0, IDs[i], trackingFeatures[i]);
        if (rotation > 0) {
            if (rotation == 1) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                    int x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = height - 1 - x;
                }
            } else if (rotation == 2) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = width - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = height - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                }
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT; ++j) {
                    int x = trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x;
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].x = width - 1 - trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y;
                    trackingFeatures[i].features[j].y = x;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    FSDK.FreeImage(cameraImage);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
    if (!isResizeCalled) {
        isResizeCalled = true;
        mainView.resizeForPerformance(width, height);
        return;
    }

    GLES11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> psize = param.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    if (psize.size() > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        int optDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Log.d(TAG, "Choosing preview resolution closer to " + width + " x " + height);

        double neededScale = height / (double) width;
        for (int j = 0; j < psize.size(); ++j) {
            double scale = psize.get(j).width / (double) psize.get(j).height;
            int distance = (int) (10000 * Math.abs(scale - neededScale));

            Log.d(TAG, "Choosing preview resolution, probing " + psize.get(j).width + " x " + psize.get(j).height + " distance: " + distance);
            if (distance < optDistance) {
                i = j;
                optDistance = distance;
            } else if (distance == optDistance) {
                if ((psize.get(i).width < 300 || psize.get(i).height < 300)
                        && psize.get(j).width > psize.get(i).width && psize.get(j).height > psize.get(i).height) {
                    i = j;
                }
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Using optimal preview size: " + psize.get(i).width + " x " + psize.get(i).height);
        param.setPreviewSize(psize.get(i).width, psize.get(i).height);
        int viewportHeight = (int) (width * (psize.get(i).width * 1.0f / psize.get(i).height));

        GLES11.glViewport(0, 0, width, viewportHeight);

        this.width = width;
        this.height = viewportHeight;
        pixelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.width * this.height * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    }

    camera.setParameters(param);
    camera.startPreview();
    inPreview = true;
    isResized = true;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
private void initTex() {
    textures = new int[3];
    GLES11.glEnable(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
    GLES11.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLES11.glGenTextures(3, textures, 0);
    GLES11.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[0]);
    GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES11.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES11.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES11.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES11.GL_NEAREST);
}

private void deleteTex() {
    GLES11.glDeleteTextures(3, textures, 0);
}

public synchronized void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture st) {
    updateSurfaceTexture = true;
    mainView.requestRender();
}

public synchronized void snapshot() {
    isTakingSnapshot.set(true);
}
```

I really think that i've written something wrong but i can't figure it so can anyone see my code or if he knows anything about the preview that is being mirrored in my case can he answer please!
Any type of help is needed and appreciated! Thank you.